# Morlet wavelet in scipy.cwt function

Tags: python, scipy, continuous, wavelet

I am using continuous wavelet transform with scipy.

In the doc the signal.ricker function is used for the wavelet:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html

The code works with the signal.ricker function which uses the mexican hat wavelet:

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pywt


sig  = data
widths = np.arange(1, 31)

cw = signal.cwt(sig, signal.ricker, widths)
```

Now I want to use instead of signal.ricker and mexican hat wavelet the morlet wavelet.

So far I have tried those morlet functions without any success:

```
morl1 = signal.morlet(125, w=5.0, s=1.0, complete=True)
```

and:

```
wavelet = pywt.ContinuousWavelet('morl')
zA, zD = wavelet.wavefun(level=8)
morl2 = zA
```

Is there any method so the morlet wavelet can be used for the continuous wavelet transform with scipy?

```
cw = signal.cwt(sig, morlet, widths)
```

Answer (score 1):

The original `signal.morlet` is not appropriate for using with the `signal.cwt`-function.

You can use [`scipy.signal.morlet2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.morlet2.html) instead, which creates a complex morlet wavelet made specially for `signal.cwt`.